# Can I, within the same file, use a previously printed line as an input to a new section?

Tags: java, for-loop, input, while-loop, output

public class Bonus1{
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int[] numbers = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
  numbers[i] = i;
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
  int r = i + (int)(Math.random() * (n - i));
  int tmp = numbers[i];
  numbers[i] = numbers[r];
  numbers[r] = tmp;
  System.out.print(numbers[i]);
}

int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int count = 0;

while(data.hasNext()){
  int y = data.nextInt();
  if(y < min){
    min = y;
    count += 1;
  }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

}
}

this code isn't complete, the first 2 for-loops will generate an array between 0 to a given number in the commandline -1
So for example java Bonus1 10 would first generate an array between 0-9 and then it will shuffle these numbers around so that it creates a random permutation.

the while loop is something I've used before to read input and determine how many times a new lowest number is detected. so for example if I get the permutation 7 8 2 3 4 5 1 0 6 9 it will count 7 as the lowest, then 2 as the lowest and then 1 as the lowest and finally 0 as the lowest, making the total amount of times a new lowest number has been detected 4.

but this only works if I use inputs, I need to use the previously generated output as the input in the same file, is there a clever way to do that?

Comment: That sounds like a really roundabout way of approaching the problem. Why not just iterate the array? That is a lot easier than trying to read back from the console output

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate for the array `numbers` like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int[] numbers = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        numbers[i] = i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int r = i + (int) (Math.random() * (n - i));
        int tmp = numbers[i];
        numbers[i] = numbers[r];
        numbers[r] = tmp;
        System.out.print(numbers[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();

    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int y = numbers[i];
        if (y < min) {
            min = y;
            ++count;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(count);
}
```

output:

```
6457098123
3
```